Convergence of a series to a function and the Fourier representation of that function
Given a sequence $ \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $, such that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ converges absolutely, show that the series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nx) $$
converges for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $. Additionally, if the sum is a function $ f(x) $, prove that $ f(x) $ is continuous, and that its Fourier series is
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nx). $$
For the first part, I used the M-test, since $ |\cos(nx)| \leq 1 $ and the fact that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is absolutely convergent. It follows that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nx) $ is uniformly convergent to some function $ f(x) $. The function $ f(x) $ is continuous because of the uniform convergence of the series and the fact that $ a_n \cos(nx) $ is continuous for all $ n $.
I am not sure about the last part: how do I show that the Fourier series of $ f(x) $ is the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nx) $?
Edit: Thanks to Srini for the comment, I substituted f(x) with $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(n x)$$, when calculating the Fourier coefficients and it worked out.

You can show that the coefficients $B_{n}$ for the sine become $0$ by showing that the integral used to compute $B_{n}$ vanishes due to orthogonality of cos and sin.

Thanks that worked, I substituted f(x) with the given series that converges uniformly to f and I worked out the coefficients an and bn for the Fourier representation.

The Fourier coefficients are coefficients of a vector to an orthogonal basis. They are unique. As the function already has the form of a Fourier series, there is nothing to calculate. It is similar to ask if the Cartesian coordinates of the vector $(1,2,3)$ are $(1,2,3)$. Or to determine the Laurent series at $z_0=0$ of $f(z)=\frac1{z^2}$.

Well, that makes sense, I don't know then why the question was phrased that way.
